# see full label in ggplot bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-bar

[image]

How can I adjust the labels on the bars so that they look complete?

Thanks in advance

```
ggplot(data=derivates, aes(x=reorder(EMPRESA, Derivates),
                      y=Derivates,
                      fill=EMPRESA,
                      width=0.5,
                      label=Derivates)) +  
    coord_flip() +  
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color="white", fill="blue") + 
    geom_text(aes(label    =format(Derivates,
                                   big.mark = "'", scientific = FALSE, digits = 0.5)), 
              hjust=-0.10, 
              size =3.0) +

    xlab(NULL) + ylab (NULL)+
    ggtitle("Derivates") +   
    theme(
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
      plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="italic"))
```

Comment: You need yo expand the limits of your x axis. Adding a `xlim()`call with the limits you want should work,

Comment: from the picture I guess it should be `xlim(0,10)` ;-)

Comment: I tried with xlim() but I have the message. "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". Here is my data. Thanks and greetings from peru: 
 https://www.dropbox.com/preview/derivates1.csv?role=personal

Answer (score 0):

someone from the web in spanish helped me.
I added in the last line of the code+

coord_flip(ylim=c(0, max(derivates$Derivates)*1.1))

and it worked perfectly

thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymLeL.png)